# Github Action w/ Firebase Private Key and extra parsed backslashes \\\\\\n

Tags: go, firebase-authentication, environment-variables, github-actions

I'm running into an issue where I am seeing the following issue related to my Firebase private key in a Github action. It doesn't seem to be being "parsed" correctly, and the action seems to be adding extra new lines into the string which is rather frustrating.

The tests pass and work locally, so it's not an issue with the environment variable not being correct. It just seems to be being injected incorrectly.

I'm specifically seeing the following problem:

```
expected: "{\"error\":\"403 Forbidden\"}"
actual  : "{\"error\":\"no private key data found in: \\\"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\\\\\\\nasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd\\\\\\\\...\\\\\\\\ndsTYSiV+aU01dYLlmraHkeH86y6MlROTmnpHi0FmsFC5CLpadpzg8HB0EKSqNEnr\\\\\\\\asdsasasasasas\\\\\\\\asasasasasasas\\\\\\\\asasasasasas\\\\\\\\nPvQFJo1GwrPjzps+QAjtveoi24hCEvbBL2NM5b9SP+dDb1GR4zKYEya6r57xOJX7\\\\\\\\nGK4mrAikx/0TWiJghkMzl48+pVfFZ/pgfkcJF+0Rep3AgVwD9/0N3bTkD1tgzSCS\\\\\\\\nklAlx/sdi+qyskJqGZrrWrA=\\\\\\\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\\\\\\\n\\\"\"}"
```

So I am seeing loads of extra backslashes?

I have added the secret as both the raw value but also wrapped in "" inside the secret itself, but neither seem to work?

What is going on? This action was working absolutely fine no more than hours ago?